# Proper or optimized test way within asp.net web api application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, tdd

We have an asp.net web api application, in which we used this architecture:

1. Presentation Layer
2. BLL layer
3. Dal Layer

We discussed, me and my colleges, about TDD and how can we used it in our project :

**My Approach**

> I see that we have to test the BLL layer by adding full unit tests
>   list, **Then** we test the presentation layer

**Other opinion**

> We have only to test the services(presentation layer). If a test
>   failed then, we test only the methods(in bll) which have relation with
>   this service

So the discussion is about

**Proper vs optimized way**

So I need to know

1. What is the best approach between them?
2. Can the size and the type of the project interfers in this comparison?

Thanks,

Comment: What's wrong with my question to vote to close it!! I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BL, your DAL should be injected as dependencies and you should be using Dependency Injection container like Unity. The reason being, your unit tests shld have no dependency to databases. When your BL tests are isolated from Databases your tests can run fast too